# Photo in icloud are corrupted

Tags: icloud, photos, photos.app

I have scanned a few photos back in Dec 2013. They were scanned by 'Image Capture' app and they were imported into icloud via Photo at least two years ago.

Today when I browsed my photo on osx, I realised they are corrupted:

[image]

When I checked my iphone they are corrupted in the same way.

I want to know how can I find out the extent of damages to my photo collection. I have imported my entire family album and there are over 40000 photo and 2500 video. It is impossible to access them one by one by myself.

Comment: Would you be able to go to the location in the Finder for any of the three photos you posted in your question, select one and hit spacebar to open it in Quick Look/Preview instead of the Photos app? With a collection that large, it may just be a rendering issue so using the step above, we can check if the image itself is in good shape. Report back with your findings.

Comment: You can't access a photo in Photo app via Finder. The photos are stored in the `Photos Library` and managed by Photo app/iCloud

Comment: I have also checked the photo on icloud.com using Google Chrome. Corrupted in the same way

Answer (score 1):

You need to contact Apple Support right away. Your iCloud account could be having functionality issues. They can put in a petition to the iCloud team so they can investigate your account.

Comment: The Apple Support are useless. Whatever problem they also asked me to log out/log in icloud. It took me hours to redownload everything. Problem always stay and they said, 'it is strange' and end of story. Escalated but no solutions. I think I have to switch to Android.

Comment: When they escalated you did you speak to a senior advisor?

Comment: They were supposed to send your case to the iCloud team

Comment: One of those in Executive Team. Usually follows the script like 'I am sorry this happened'. Next talking point will then be '... but I am not technical person so I will hook you up with a support'. Throw me back to a junior support who will then ask me to log out/log in yet one more time then throw me to a 'Senior icloud' expert who promised to get back to me. Every f**king time.

Comment: Smh. Unfortunately they will have to at least forward the case over to the iCloud department so that they can investigate the issue. You aren't the only customer that has had things get corrupt in iCloud. That iCloud departmant can do repairs to your iCloud account. If you feel up to it, I'd recommend giving it another shot. Just be specific with them as far as what you want done. Dont speak to a level 1 tech. Ask for a senior advisor and then get their contact information so that you can stay on top of them.

Comment: There were a time I have to talk to their icloud support at least once a months to fix login and sync issues for several months. Each call took hours and my days were totally ruined. I don't think I can stomach it again. I just want to a way to access damage and see if I can recover some family memory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72791/discussion-between-melvin-jefferson-and-anthony-kong).